# How to instantiate subclasses during deserialisation in F#

Tags: inheritance, f#, polymorphism, deserialization

I have a byte array that I would like to deserialise into a concrete class in F#.  The first byte consists of a 'type' that can be used to infer the type of message to expect.  There are potentially many message types, and these are subclasses of a base class that provides common methods, for example:

```
/// The base message class
type public BaseMessage() =
    member val MessageType:uint8 = 0uy with get, set

    with
        static member ReadHeader(br:BinaryReader) =
            br.ReadByte()

        static member FromStream(br:BinaryReader) =
            let messageType = BaseMessage.ReadHeader(br)

            BaseMessage(MessageType = messageType)

/// The first message type
type public SubMessageA() =
    inherit BaseMessage()

    member val Desc = "" with get, set

    with
        static member FromStream(br:BinaryReader) =
            let messageType = BaseMessage.ReadHeader(br)
            let chars = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(br.ReadBytes(4))

            new SubMessageA(MessageType = messageType,
                Desc = new string(chars))    

/// The second message type
type public SubMessageB() =
    inherit BaseMessage()

    member val Value = 0 with get, set

    with
        static member FromStream(br:BinaryReader) =
            let messageType = BaseMessage.ReadHeader(br)
            let value = br.ReadInt32()

            new SubMessageB(MessageType = messageType,
                Value = value)
```

Now the question:  The method above requires that I implement some kind of pattern matching on the message type **outside of the class** via some extra Factory.  Is there a better way to do this?  It feels like inheritance should be able to avoid such 'switch statement' like behaviour and automatically handle such cases, but I'm unsure how.

Alternatively I could have some common method **inside the base class** that contained the pattern matching, but then that is a violation of the open-closed principal - ideally I'd like to be able to handle extra types without having to touch the base class!

I realise this is not exactly idiomatic F# but for various reasons I need to stick to classes here.  Thanks for any advice!

Comment: No, think about it. No matter how do you implement it at some point you need something that know all the existing classes and this already breaks the principle. That's normal since deserializing is an [aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_(computer_programming)), so it has to be implemented as a special thing.

Comment: Many thanks Gustavo, if I had enough reputation I would upvote your comment!  I ended up creating the factory class which is working really well.